# Organizing objects in html5 webgl canvas animation with three.js

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, webgl, three.js

I want to draw a 3D cat(with animation) which is no more than a bunch of 3D objects - ellipsoids, pyramids, spheres, etc. 
And I have 2 questions:

1) Are there any ways to define your own complex geometrical 3D objects rather than standard Three.js objects such as Sphere, Cube...

2) When animation the whole cat should I define an animation function for each object? Is there any way to combine some objects together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For question one I'd recommend reading up on [parameter driven modelling](http://www.cadalyst.com/cad/autocad/parametrics-driven-drawings-4799), this will allow you to make consistent complex objects without reinventing the wheel every time you create one. As for creating the custom objects, much like in the way polylines are are effectively a collection of lines with iterative implementations of the standard line methods (as well as object-specific methods) you'd create a javascript object which contains a collection of the objects necessary to create your custom shape. [Here's](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/webgl_cheat_sheet/WebGL_Cheat_Sheet.htm) a good webgl cheat sheet to help you out a bit.

Question two is somewhat similar to the way we've described complex objects above in that while you'll write a Cat object render / animate function, you'll handle the animation on a per object basis (with the exception full object static movement, imagine a cat on an escalator). Once again constraint, or parameter driven design will be your saviour here since the fact that two or more objects are partially superposed in no way means that the objects are explicitly linked.

As an end note I'd recommend looking into [clojurescript](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki). It might not be necessary for this type of work but lisp is very popular in the CAD scripting world and you'd definitely be doin' yourself a favour in the long run by at least familiarising yourself with the coding conventions - a lot of the questions you're goin' to have whilst working on this project will be answered in a variety of programming languages but you'll likely find that many of the answers that were written by folk working on both sides of the fence (cad/programming) will be written in lisp. Here's a final general [CAD forum](http://cadtutor.net) that's a great resource for all things CAD.